# Match colors in feColorMatrix filter

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I have a greyscale image. I want to filter it such that `white -> color1` and `black -> color2`. Both colors are in hex CSS syntax. What math do I need to do to get this effect?

I'm using this syntax:

```
<!-- just an example -->
<filter id="colorMeMatrix">
  <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
    type="matrix"
    values="0 0 0 0 0
            1 1 1 1 0
            0 0 0 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0" />
```

Comment: I don't have time to write it up right now, but this might get you started: http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/AiHEJ

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To understand the matrix you need, you have to clearly define what you're starting with, what you want to end up with, and how the [colour matrix filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) works.

The matrix has five columns and four rows.  Each row represents one of the output numbers: R,G,B,A.  The columns represent your input RGBA and a constant 1.  You calculate the output value for each row by adding up each of the values in the row multiplied by the corresponding input value.

Both the input and the output numbers are standardized to the range 0-1, so you don't have to worry about multiplying everything by 256.

So for the matrix in your example:

```
      /*R G B A 1 */
        0 0 0 0 0 // R = 0*R + 0*G + 0*B + 0*A + 0
        1 1 1 1 0 // G = 1*R + 1*G + 1*B + 1*A + 0
        0 0 0 0 0 // B = 0*R + 0*G + 0*B + 0*A + 0
        0 0 0 1 0 // A = 0*R + 0*G + 0*B + 1*A + 0
```

It takes the input color, adds up all four channels (RGBA) and makes the result the green channel.  The red and blue channels are zero and the alpha channel isn't changed.  So your picture ends up with black areas still black, but all coloured/gray/white/transparent areas are converted into shades of green.

That's not what you wanted, of course.  You wanted to have black areas one colour and white areas another colour, and all gray areas somewhere in between the two.

To make black areas a certain colour, you have to set the constant-factor parameters of your matrix.  The input RGB values are going to be zero for black, so they don't factor in at this point.

If your colour2, the value you want to use for black in your monochrome image,  is (r2, g2, b2), then that's what your constant factors have to be:

```
      /*R G B A 1  */
        ? ? ? 0 r2 // R = ?*0 + ?*0 + ?*0 + 0*0 + r2 = r2
        ? ? ? 0 g2 // G = ?*0 + ?*0 + ?*0 + 0*0 + g2 = g2
        ? ? ? 0 b2 // B = ?*0 + ?*0 + ?*0 + 0*0 + b2 = b2
        0 0 0 1 0  // A = 1*A
```

Of course, the above matrix will turn *any* input colour into that output colour, because it doesn't factor in anything from the input RGBA values.  To get the gradient you want, you need white areas -- those with input values of 1 for R, G, and B, to end up with your colour1, which I'm going to write as (r1, g1, b1).

Now, to make things a little easier, remember that for a grayscale image the R, G and B values for any point will be equal.  So we can just use any one of those values as the input and ignore the others.  So if we just set the R-factor for each channel, when the input value is white the input R equals 1 and the equations are

```
      /*R G B A 1  */
        ? 0 0 0 r2 // R = ?*1 + r2 = r1
        ? 0 0 0 g2 // G = ?*1 + g2 = g1
        ? 0 0 0 b2 // B = ?*1 + b2 = b1
        0 0 0 1 0  // A = 1*A
```

Simple algebra tells you that in order to make those equations work, you need to replace the question marks with the difference between the colour1 and colour2 values:

```
      /*   R    G B A 1  */
        (r1-r2) 0 0 0 r2 // R = (r1-r2)*1 + r2 = r1
        (g1-g2) 0 0 0 g2 // G = (g1-g2)*1 + g2 = g1
        (b1-b2) 0 0 0 b2 // B = (b1-b2)*1 + b2 = b1
           0    0 0 1 0  // A = 1*A
```

For example, if you want white areas of the input image to map to cyan (r=0,g=1,b=1) and your black input areas to map to a deep purple (r=0.1, g=0, b=0.2), you would use a matrix like

```
        /*R  G B A  1  */
        -0.1 0 0 0 0.1 // R = (-0.1)*R + 0.1
          1  0 0 0  0  // G = 1*R + 0
         0.8 0 0 0 0.2 // B = 0.8*R + 0.2
          0  0 0 1  0  // A = 1*A
```

[Using that matrix in a filter](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/mtKiH)  applied to [this original image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:113766main_04272005_tinyCrators_grey_equal.png).

Note that this is actually quite different from the example I linked to in a comment; in that filter, I was trying to maintain white as white and black as black, but change the grays to colour.  For that I used a gamma correction filter, not a colour matrix.

Comment: Very well explained !!

Comment: You'll probably want to add a color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" attribute to your filter - it gives more natural color interpolation for images (it's gamma-corrected)

Comment: @MichaelMullany  I hadn't played around with that -- it does make a huge difference, although I don't know that the sRGB version is necessarily better.  You just have to know what you want, and make sure that you're calculating the RGB values for your colours in the correct colour space.  I've updated the [linked example](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/mtKiH) to compare.

Comment: I think most jpg's and pngs out there are in sRGB, so I think for most images, sRGB is likely to give you the "right" result in the sense that it's probably the result you're looking for. Although it couldn't hurt to pop open the metadata and see what the color profile is. The SVG spec isn't all that clear on exactly how the different color spaces are supposed to be applied. I've seen processing linearRGB in Safari give results that don't look anything like results from any of the other browsers. sRGB seems to give good cross-browser fidelity.

Comment: Well, if you're starting from grayscale, the starting colour profile isn't relevant.  But if you're trying to match colours in another image, then it certainly would be.  And if the sRGB spec is more clearly defined and consistent cross-browser, that would be a big argument in its favour.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly (I'm trying to match the output from TeX to solarized).

Comment: @MichaelMullany's recommendation to add `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` achieved the effect I was looking for. Basically I had a desired target color (#002A78) and the following filter now correctly maps the full source to said target:       `<feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="source" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
            values="0 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 0.17
                    0 0 0 0 0.47
                    0 0 0 1 0" />`

Comment: @MichaelMullany thank you, you saved me a day! With color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" filter colors (0.5, 0.44 etc) are mapping to RGB linearly: 0.5 0.5 0.5 is exactly rgb(128, 128, 128).

Comment: Color spaces are a real rabbit hole - glad to help